# Laravel + Angular 2 integration

Tags: angular, laravel, laravel-5

After working with many different frameworks (Symfony, Ruby-On-Rails, Angular) I discovered [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) framework, and find it very nice.

I would like to combine the advantages of Laravel as a backend app with the possibilities of creating a great frontend with Angular 2.

I managed to integrate them manually, by creating an Angular app, then [deploy it](https://angular.io/guide/deployment), and then export it to the public directory of my laravel app.

I also found [this article](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-53-with-angular-2-1).

However, **I find it hard to believe that there is no easier way**.
I would love to take advantage of great [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/) and [composer](https://getcomposer.org/), and let them do the work for me, but haven't find anything about it.

(I found [this one](https://laravel-angular.io/), but couldn't manage to make it work...)

Is there some out-of-the-box solution?

Comment: Give this a try https://github.com/toni-rmc/laravel-angular-integration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple way, in my opinion, while keeping Angular and Laravel 2 as decoupled as possible and without having to use a third party package, is by writing a small bash script to do this for you.

You would start your Laravel server as normal, start your Angular development server as normal, and when you're ready to deploy you just run a one line script to build your Angular project and move the files to the respective Laravel folders, and voila.

The only prerequisite is that you need to have your Laravel routes include a catchall that directs every request to `resourves/views/index.blade.php`.

Here's a script I made a while ago:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

green='\033[1;32m'
nc='\033[0m'

say()
{
    printf "${green}=> $1${nc}\n"
}

cp_to_laravel()
{
    say 'Removing old files from public'
    rm -rf public/assets
    mkdir public/assets

    say 'Copying "client/dist" to "public/assets"'
    cp -r client/dist/ public/assets/

    say 'Flattening assets'
    cp -r public/assets/assets/ public/assets/
    rm -rf public/assets/assets

    say 'Copying "client/dist/index.html" to "resources/views/index.blade.php"'
    cp client/dist/index.html resources/views/index.blade.php

    say 'Build complete!'
}

say 'Building client with --aot and --prod'
cd client
ng build --aot --prod
cd ..
cp_to_laravel
```

From the root of your Laravel project, run the script with `bash build-client.sh` or `sh build-client.sh`.

The script above assumes your project structure looks something like this:

```
- app
- bootstrap
- client // Angular project inside here
    - dist
    - node_modules
    - src
    .angular-cli.json
    // ...
- config
- database
- public
- resources
- routes
- storage
- tests
build-client.sh
// ...
```

**This is what it does:**

1. CD's into your angular project and runs `ng build -prod -aot` to build the project.
2. Calls the `cp_to_laravel` function, which does the following:

   - gets rid of the contents in `public/assets` in case there were any previous files there from a previous build
   - copies the built files from `client/dist` into `public/assets`
   - gets rid of the double asset folders by moving the contents of `public/assets/assets` into `public/assets` (this is necessary because `ng build -prod -aot` will create it's own assets folder, which is why there is a duplicate
   - copies the contents of `client/dist/index.html` into `resources/views/index.blade.php`